# mongoDB - how to remove a member from a replicaset, and then start a new one?

Tags: mongodb

I had a prototype where I created a replica set with 3 members.  Now I want to remove 2 of the secondaries from the replicaset, and create new replicas on each of the secondaries.

From the primary, I did the following:

```
rs.remove("mongohost2.domain.org:27017")
rs.remove("mongohost3.domain.org:27017")
```

Then when i tried a rs.status(), it correctly showed only the primary in the set.

Now, on the secondary2.domain.org box, I did the following:

1. changed the mongo.conf file - changed the replicaset name from the old one (jls0) to jls1.
2. restarted mongod on the box.

**Problem:**

When I start the shell I can tell that it didn't create the replicaset because the prompt doesn't have the name of the replica like it used to.

This is what I get:

```
me@mongohost2:~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
> rs.status()
{
    "startupStatus" : 1,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "loading local.system.replset config (LOADINGCONFIG)"
}
> rs.initiate()
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "local.oplog.rs is not empty on the initiating member.  cannot initiate."
}
>
```

And I found this in the logs:

```
2014-11-25T15:11:38.876-0500 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2014-11-25T15:11:38.957-0500 [rsStart] warning: Failed to connect to 10.238.59.71:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-25T15:11:38.961-0500 [rsStart] replSet REMOVED
2014-11-25T15:11:38.961-0500 [rsStart] replSet info self not present in the repl set configuration:
2014-11-25T15:11:38.961-0500 [rsStart] { _id: "jls0", version: 8, members: [ { _id: 0, host: "mongohost1:27017", priority: 3.0 }, { _id: 2, host: "mongohost3.domain.org:27017" } ] }
2014-11-25T15:11:38.964-0500 [rsStart] warning: Failed to connect to 10.238.59.71:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-25T15:11:38.964-0500 [rsStart] replSet info Couldn't load config yet. Sleeping 20sec and will try again.
2014-11-25T15:11:39.237-0500 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.238.59.141:39443 #1 (1 connection now open)
2014-11-25T15:11:39.237-0500 [conn1] replSet set names do not match, our cmdline: jls1
2014-11-25T15:11:39.237-0500 [conn1] replSet s: jls0
2014-11-25T15:11:58.967-0500 [rsStart] warning: Failed to connect to 10.238.59.71:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-11-25T15:11:58.967-0500 [rsStart] replSet info Couldn't load config yet. Sleeping 20sec and will try again.
2014-11-25T15:11:59.241-0500 [conn1] replSet set names do not match, our cmdline: jls1
2014-11-25T15:11:59.241-0500 [conn1] replSet s: jls0
```

What other steps do I need to do to ensure that this server is now using it's own replicaset? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `rs.initialize()` when setting up a new replica set.

You might also to delete your old data files before initializing the new set, or perhaps only the local.* files where the replica setup information is stored.

Comment: Good point re: deleting old data.  but the command I had to run was rs.initiate()